# Will running multiple jobs at a 5 min rate clog the server?

Tags: jenkins

I'm running currently 10 jobs at every 5 mins. Every build takes less than 2 seconds. I have added the following settings to each build:

->Discard old builds:

```
Days to keep builds 1
Max # of builds to keep 5
```

->Post-build Actions:

```
Days to keep builds 1
Max # of builds to keep 5
Interval to keep old builds (by days) 1
Interval to keep old builds (by # of builds) 5
```

Will this create huge log files or demand high cpu/memory activity?
The server has 6 cores, 8gb of ram and 200 gb ssd.
Recently I had a problem where Jenkins created a log file having 150gb. Also the CPU was 120%+. After deleting the log file and restarting Jenkins all activity went back to normal. I've monitored the logs for the last past days and they currently have less than 2MB.

Is it safe to run jobs at every 5 min? For example the jobs are simple, check if the response code of a website is 200 and if not send me an email, another job is checking the cpu/mem/free space of the host and if there is less than x gb free email me.
Also what would happen with the build number after a year for example.

Currently I have jobs that are at #200+ builds. Is there a way to reset the number of builds after lets say 100 builds, reset it back to 0? Does a higher number a build affect the server (as in are old builds kept somewhere if I have the settings mentioned above?)?

LE Edit:
Jenkins seems to start again to create huge log files: currently 50gb + and using much cpu / memory:

https://imgur.com/a/7Xj3qoo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbMRI.jpg

tail on jenkins.log:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4CCY.jpg

Why is this happening? All jobs are successfully and with a build time less than 2 secs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re: overloading your server:

There should be no problem running a job every 5 minutes, the number of jobs you can run depends on the available build executors - if you have for example 4 executors setup than 4 jobs can run at the same time (the others will queue up). You can change the executor's settings or add more jenkins slaves to your jenkins setup if you need to scale the number of jobs you can run. You can also setup some monitoring on your server if you worry about breaking stuff - if it's in the cloud, you can mostly see the metrics and set alerts in there, or you can install datadog agent and monitor your disk/cpu/ram via datadog, there are many other options and tools to help you to keep on top of the server performance.

re: build numbers - I believe it will be hard to reach the max build number as it's very high. If you will want to reset the build history and set the build number back to 1, you can try to follow [this blog](http://codeketchup.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-clean-and-reset-jenkins-build.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, currently jenkins is acting up, I have edited the first post, can you take a look please?

Comment: @rooger It looks like you may be affected by [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25369). There are multiple linked issues which are describing the same problem you are seeing. Perhaps try to disable DNS Multicast as suggested could resolve your issue?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have added    
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.DNSMultiCast.disabled=true -Dhudson.udp=-1"

And jenkins seems to be back to normal, at least for the moment, will open another thread in the future if the problem persist. Thank you for your help